# translate aov to lmer

Tags: r, lme4, anova, multilevel-analysis

I'm stuck here. How to translate the following command lines to lmer syntax.

```r
model <- aov(
  response ~ treatment*time + Error(id/time),
  data = selfesteem2)
summary(model)
```

I've tried this among others without success.

```r
anova(lmerTest::lmer(
  response ~ treatment*time + (1|id:time),
  data = selfesteem2))
```

---

The data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data("selfesteem2", package = "datarium")
selfesteem2 <- selfesteem2 %>% # long format
  pivot_longer(c("t1","t2","t3"), values_to = "score", names_to = "time") %>% 
  mutate(time = factor(time)) %>% 
  rename(response = score)
```

Comment: what are the errors

Comment: The example data you gave has columns id, group, time, score. Can you please adjust your example to match it ?

Comment: No errors. I would like to reproduce the same output in both methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's

```r
anova(lmerTest::lmer(
  response ~ treatment*time + (1|id/time),
  data = selfesteem2))
```

Comment: But the F-values are not the same as in aov().

Comment: @Nip Try the options `type="1", ddf="Kenward-Roger"` in `anova`. Then the sum-of-squares are the same.

Comment: Using `anova(..., type="1", ddf="Kenward-Roger")` doesn't seem to affect the results.

Comment: @Nip Sorry, I meant the ddf.

Comment: I cannot get the same F-values. When I use the `anova(lmerTest::lmer())` as in the question, only the F-value of "time" differs from the `aov()` output.
I would like to know whether is possible to get the same F-values for the variables and their interaction in both `aov()` and `anova(lmerTest::lmer())`.

Comment: This might end up being a [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexhange.com) question. I note that the underlying `lmer` model is singular (the `time:id` variance is estimated as zero), which is going to make this tricky.

Comment: I guess the fact that there are duplicate ids across between-subjects variables has something to do with this. Thus, "treatment" is not a between-subjects effect, rather is it within-subjects effect.

Comment: @BenBolker I voted for the migration to CV.